# Store enum in database

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I have a database for a job advertisement web application for an assignment at university.
I have a lot of enumeration values in database such as names of the cities, categories of the advertisement or list of languages.
Part of the database:
[image]

My aim was to prevent user to send via input and create some invalid data, e.g. we want the values like 'LA', "L.A." and "Los Angeles" to be represented by one ID from the `city` table.
I also thought it is good idea to store it in database table because with given set of values, I could treat them as tags and it would improve the process of searching. Also it is easy to expand those values, e.g. add new language to list.

Unfortunatelly professor said that this is not an optimal solution, so my question is what is the best way to store easily expandable list of enum values in situation like the above?

I am using PostgreSQL and application will be build with Java EE running on Glassfish.

Comment: That seems perfectly fine to me. You should ask your teacher why he considers it to not be a good solution.

Comment: I am a little bit confused... are you planing to create an Java enum representing the possible values on the database or just to have a database with a limited number of options where the user should select from?

Comment: I don't see any problem to store enums in database. But you should use some cache tool like ehcache in your app. Cities are not modified often so you can cache values in memory and you donť have to hit database for every request.

Comment: @marcellorvalle Initially I wanted to store the values in database, but right now I am looking for different/better solution (if exists).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this may seem to make sense from a purely architectural perspective, I would classify this as a database design anti-pattern.  Fundamentally, this is an inappropriate use of enumerations. Your apparent goal is to prevent the user from ever entering an incorrect value by forcing them to choose from a list of correct values.  While noble, your goal is ultimately flawed for the following reasons:

1. It is beyond the scope of the DBA to maintain an accurate list of every city on the planet. Cities crop up with far more regularity than you might imagine, and there is no easy comprehensive list that you can copy from.
2. As you cannot maintain a comprehensive list, you and/or your application will require a mechanism to enter new values. This will defeat your goal of guaranteeing correct values.
3. This is an over-normalization of your database schema.  You really don't want to have to do complex joins just to determine the value of a single field of information.

Alternative solutions would be to maintain a list of known good names, and use autocompletion to *suggest* known correct values, but allow your user to enter a new value that is not on the list. Do not store the city as an enumeration, but store it directly with the rest of it's logically grouped data.

Comment: What if I want to have really small list of cities like in this example: http://www.indeed.com/l-California-jobs.html ? I will have ~50 biggest cities of my country to choose from and also application will allow user to enter own city name, and same rules applied to storing universities. And how about immutable list of businesses and categories of advertisements?

Comment: Using a list of "known good" cities for the purposes of an autocomplete UI would be fine, but storing the data as an enum would not be recommended. The use of an enum would still create the problem of over-normalization.

Comment: So in this case e.g. tables `city` and `employer` have no connection in ERD? And `employee` has a column `city` storing string value instead of `city_id`?

Comment: I would recommend that the city table as it currently is used be eliminated, and that all references to city_id be replaced with city columns storing the actual city. If you want to have a lookup table of city names for autocompletion purposes, that is fine, but I would refrain from trying to normalize cities out to their own table. In actual use this would be counterproductive.

Comment: In database design classes and books, sometimes the benefits of normalization and enforcing integrity are overemphasized, and the costs associated with these goals are not properly addressed. A database which is fully normalized and completely constrained might be considered the relational "ideal". In real world use, this results in a database which involves overly complex queries that are very hard to maintain, and constraints that seem reasonable in design become impractical in real use. I think your professor is considering that with regard to the city table.

Comment: Exactly, sometimes at university we are "forced" to normalize every table and create SQL queries containing eight JOINs and such solution was considered correct. Thank you for your suggestions.